# how to protect direct angular get function

Tags: angularjs, laravel, security, request

I have an angularjs controller where i call to many reports like this :

```
if(reporttype==21){
$scope.framesrc={src:"http://localhost/myapi/report21Service"+$scope.brandid}
}
if (reporttype=22_}
...
}
```

I can not create here a post request, am generating reports and a long huge story.

My question is, is there anyway to avoid users to call this request if they are outside the website? because now if you put the link in any tab, it will return all my data. Is there any way other than the post functinons and stuff ? like specify the origin of the request or something like this.

Answer (score 1):

Well you have to implement a `CSRF` protection on your laravel server. its a simple concept, your server will generate a `CSRF token` on login or something and when you access the  `api` you will attach the token with the `request`.

Refer [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) for more info. and [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/csrf) to implement `CSRF` on laravel.

Answer (score 0):

If you have authentication, you can use a token to authenticate the user.
Another solution could be to block cross domain acess in your server.

Answer (score 0):

ok solved,

first after the user login, I get the userid in session, then while accessing the api, if isset session userid return result, else return error. Now accessing the api outside the project without login is impossible.

PS: if the user login and tries another id, for other users, in the beginning of the function there's a condition that if he pass a parameter outside the result of the query that returns his brands, the report returns an error too.